# Can't run grails app on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

I have some problem when running grails app in eclipse IDE.
In terminal all is fine.

```
JAVA -version 
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Grails 
Version: 3.0.5
| Groovy Version: 2.4.4
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_60

On Eclipse IDE grails version is 2.4.4

This is the error I get:

```
| Error 2015-09-13 15:33:27,072 [Thread-8] ERROR jvm.JVM  - Problems copying constructor. Incompatible JVM?

Message: null
   Line | Method
->> 745 | run in java.lang.Thread
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: Can not copy a non-root Constructor
->> 745 | run in java.lang.Thread
```

Can someone help me? Maybe I should change grails version in eclipse ?

Comment: Are you sure eclipse isn't using 1.8.0_40? I think there was a problem with that one

Comment: Which grails version are you exactly using. I can see two things Grails Version: 3.0.5 | Groovy Version: 2.4.4 | JVM Version: 1.8.0_60 and On Eclipse IDE grails version is 2.4.4 . You have mentioned two grails version 3.0.5 and 2.4.4 are you sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I find you need to upgrade your Eclipse IDE grails version to 3.0.5 . It is using 2.4.4 version of grails.